# Camera2 - Set ISO manually while keeping the FLASH_MODE as FLASH_MODE_TORCH

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to set ISO 100 while keeping the Flash on as I can do with [OpenCamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) and [HedgeCam2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.caddish_hedgehog.hedgecam2)

In order to do this I have to set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF) and then I can change the CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY

But the problem arise when I also try to set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH), if I turn off auto exposure control then my device turn off the torch as well.

```kotlin
val previewRequest: CaptureRequest.Builder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
previewRequest.addTarget(previewSurface)
previewRequest.apply {
    set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
    set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF)
    set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, 100)
}
cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest.build(), captureCallbacks, backgroundHandler)
```

**Update:**
Setting TEMPLATE_MANNUAL is not supported in my device but somehow those 2 applications manage to do it, with TEMPLATE_PREVIEW